# Limit Disk usage in Docker+MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, google-cloud-logging

I am using the official mongo Docker image to start a MongoDB container where my boot disk is limited (e.g. 10G) I configured the docker to run with Google Cloud Logging driver and was hoping Google to store all the logs and save my local disk space. However, I notice the disk continues to grow:

```
$ df -h
/dev/sda1       9.9G  4.5G  4.9G  49%
```

As I digged deeper I realized the size of docker containers seems to be growing over time.

```
$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/
3.6G    /var/lib/docker/
```

However, I can't go further as somehow I can't access the directories within.

If I go inside the docker and `du -sh` the root, I don't find any suspicious directories occupying space.

So my problem is how do I find out where the disk space is used and how do I eliminate it.

My docker startup command (shown without project options)

```
docker run -d --log-driver=gcplogs mongo mongod
```

EDIT: I noticed the size growing has stopped at 4.5GB from ~3GB for a while. So I supposed it has reached some equilibrium now.

Comment: what version of docker image you have?

Comment: I have mongo:latest

Comment: so probably is 3.2.3 with WT as storage engine - could you check that?

Comment: Yes it is WT. However, I noticed that the size stops at 4.5G now. So maybe it reaches some sort of equilibrium now?

Comment: Are your `docker ps -aqf status=exited`, `docker images -qf dangling=true`, and `docker volume ls -qf dangling=true` outputs relatively short? I often use a script to clean these up.

Comment: Yes, in fact I am running them on a clean instance, so there are not many other images. However, it seems the size has stop growing on 4.5G, for some reason.